# Nondeterministic ball bounce[SOLVED]

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am getting different behaviors with exactly the same execution and world settings. As you can see in [this video](https://youtu.be/b3K5pQBGAKg) , I reset the world every time and launch the ball with exactly the same velocity. This happens when launching the ball against any kind of surface (not only this board).

Update: more videos: [vid2](https://youtu.be/0puk9pH7qok), [vid3](https://youtu.be/mmKSkHYlArA).

Ball model.sdf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="basketball">
    <static>false</static>
    <self_collide>true</self_collide>
    <link name="ball">
      <inertial>
        <mass>0.25</mass>
        <!-- inertia based on solid sphere 2/5 mr^2 -->
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.00169</ixx>
          <iyy>0.00169</iyy>
          <izz>0.00169</izz>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.13</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.13</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0.5</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>0.1</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <ode>
              <max_vel>5</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0.0001</min_depth>
            </ode>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14461/nondeterministic-ball-bounce%5Bsolved%5D/) by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After testing different parameters changing the following seems to be a decent fix:

Gazebo->Physics->solver->iterations = 100 (default is 50)

---

Originally posted by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) with karma: 90 on 2016-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice_ly](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/52118/alice_ly/) on 2021-08-15**:
excuse me， but where to set the interation? And does a .world file suport that?